# Change the rigidbody constraints with a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a game, I am trying to get it so that when it is touching the player the constraints are changed.

Here is my code

```
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "player")
        {
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX;// | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
        }
    }
```

`Assets\Scripts\Pick_up.cs(42,30): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.RigidbodyConstraints' to 'UnityEngine.RigidbodyConstraints2D'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Would you be able to help me get this working?

Thanks!

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "player")
        {
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX;// | 
            RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `rb`?

Comment: it was rigidbody2d

Comment: Then could you post your entire script with minimal reproducible example?

Comment: it is in the question underneath thanks

Comment: The answer by @Sync would work for you, in `OnCollisionEnter2D` just use `rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;`

Comment: now it works thanks :) i'll mark their answer as right yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RigidbodyConstraints2D and RigidbodyConstraints are different enum types.

you should use

```
rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it comes up with: "Assets\Scripts\Pick_up.cs(49,32): error CS0117: 'RigidbodyConstraints2D' does not contain a definition for 'constraints'" and "Assets\Scripts\Pick_up.cs(49,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: it means rb.constraints is readonly.what type is rb

Comment: so what do i do here?

Comment: @Help Have you declared your `rb` as `RigidbodyConstraints2D`? just change that to `Rigidbody2D`

Comment: no it is as Rigidbody2D,